# Limit of an integral of a continuous real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

> If $f:[0,{\infty})\to\mathbb R$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to\infty}  f(x)=a$.
>   Show that:
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\ \mathsf dt = a.
> $$

If:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1x \int_{0}^{x}\ f(t)=
 \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} (F(x)-F(0))\ \mathsf dt$$

and $F(0)$ is some constant, all I need to show is $F(x)= xa$.

This is where I am not sure how I should continue, if I what I did is correct, how should I continue?

Comment: This is the continuous version of a famous discrete operation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro And the relationship of Cesaro and L'Hospital's rule is exposed upon using the latter to show the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = a$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(x) - a| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \ge M$. So for $x > M$,

$$\left|\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt - a\right| \le \frac{1}{x}\int_0^M |f(t) - a|\, dt + \frac{1}{x}\int_M^x |f(t) - a|\, dt < \frac{C}{x} + \frac{\epsilon(x - M)}{x},$$

where $C = \int_0^M |f(t) - a|\, dt$. Hence

$$\limsup_{x\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt - a\right| \le \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: I was adding Method 2 to my post when your comment came in and I didn't see that you were taking this approach also.  Oh well.  It's good to see alignment.

Comment: Why can you pull a in to the integral?

Comment: @Ridaliat note $a = \frac{1}{x}(ax) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x a\, dt$. So $$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt - a = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x (f(t) - a)\, dt.$$

Comment: Thank you for your fast response

Comment: @Ridaliat did you understand the solution?

Comment: I do, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

[L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) comes to the rescue.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}{x}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=a
\end{align}$$

---

**METHOD 2:**

If one does not wish to appeal to L'Hospital's Rule, then another approach is to take a similar way forward to that of the OP.  Here,  we don't show that $F(x)=xa$.

Rather, we recognize that for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a number $L$ such that for $x>L$, $a-\epsilon<f(x)<a+\epsilon$.  Then, we can write for such a fixed $L$

$$\left|\frac1x\int_0^xf(t)\,dt-a\right|\le\frac1x\int_0^L|f(t)-a|\,dt+\frac1x\int_L^x|f(t)-a|\,dt \tag 1$$

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ goes to zero as $x\to \infty$ while the second integral is less than $\epsilon$.  And the proof is complete.

Comment: Hi Dr. MV, at the last step, $f(a)$ should instead be $a$.

Comment: @kobe Yes, good catch!! +1  And nice to have you back!  Always enjoy reading your answers.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.